# How many plants must be grown.. | combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

A type of flower can flourish in 10 different colours. How many plants must be grown at least if you want to make a **row** of pure colours
from 4 plants, but can't see the future flower colour of a seed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, the (extended) pigeonhole principle will be helpful. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Pigeonhole_Principle

Comment: i will look it up, thanks @79037662

Comment: What does a **row** mean?  If you're planting them in one long row, you can never rule out the case of e.g. red, yellow, red, yellow, alternating, so you can never guarantee there are $4$ of the same colors next to each other.

Comment: @antkam thought the same, that's why I'm really confused with this exercise

Comment: Hmm...  have you posted the _exact wording_ of the problem?  And all the relevant info?  E.g. this isn't part (B) of a bigger question where part (A), not shown in this post, actually contains extra info?

Comment: The trick is probably that the seeds are planted in a $2$D plane, and a "row" of flowers consists of any four flowers which are colinear. For example, if you plant $11$ seeds, you are guaranteed to find a "row" of $2$ plants of the same color, since any two same-colored flowers are colinear.

Comment: @antkam Yep, just this information is provided

Comment: @MikeEarnest - ah, you mean the row of $4$ (or $2$ in your example) does not have to be consecutive, with no other colors in between?  That would make sense, esp. if this question comes from a basic combinatorics class.